# Function Prototype inside struct - Intellisense cannot find

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to switch a project of me from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2015 Community. Unfortunatly intellisense no longer can find function prototypes inside structs, so no auto complete is avaliable for these functions.

My structs look like these:

```
#ifdef SHOW_STRUCT
struct System
#else
struct SYSTEM
#endif
{
    /// <summary>
    /// blabla
    /// </summary>
    void Reset(void); 

} System;
```

Whereas `SHOW_STRUCT` is not defined (I need this special construction for compatibility with doxygen and Visual Studio 2008).

When I want to use the functon `System.Reset()`, intellisense says after typing `System.` that there are no members avaliable. Variables inside of a struct are found.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a setting which is wrong in my visual studio, any ideas?

Comment: You could try exiting VS then deleting your Solution's Code Browser Database file. It is the big *.sdf file in your Solution's folder.  It will be rebuilt the next time VS loads your Solution.

Comment: I tried that, also no luck with that. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I worked with *.c files. But the functionality I wanted is only supported in C++. So switching the project to C++ solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply typing System.Reset, intellisense might not find it because Reset is not a static function of System.  It seems to me that you either need to have an instance of System in order for intellisense to start giving member functions, or declare Reset as static.

Comment: I tried both suggested fixes of you, unfortunatly none of tem work. Still the same message.

Comment: I thought that at first, but notice the `System` on the last line of the snippet. Regardless of whether SHOW_STRUCT is defined, one instance called `System` is defined here.